# VOLTTRON vctl status

Tags: python, volttron

I have a VOLTTRON edge device that I have been working on remotely through SSH and for some reason when I run a `vctl status` I get a:

```
vctl status
VOLTTRON is not running. This command requires VOLTTRON platform to be running
```

But if I do a `tail -f volttron.log` volttron is clearly running in the background I can see all the BACnet info, etc.. See screenshot below of the log. Any ideas what is happening? Would I just reboot the volttron edge device?

[image]

Comment: How did you start the volttron?  Did you use volttron -vv -l volttron.log& or ./start-volttron script?  Did you have a different VOLTTRON_HOME?  What version of volttron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the ./start-volttron.sh script within the volttron repository you will see the line

```
volttron -vv -l volttron.log > volttron.log 2>&1 &
disown
```

This will allow you to start up and have it be available from ssh the next time you login.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `python --trace` to track down the offending issue? The first line of the `vtcl` source code will show you the proper python command to use with the `--trace` option.

`~/volttron$ /home/volttron/volttron/env/bin/python -m trace --trace ./env/bin/vctl status`